# Populate and Pass an Array of Structures to Java

Tags: java, c++, jna

I have spent a large portion of the morning trying to populate and pass an array of populated structs to C++ from Java using JNA.  I have significant portions of JNA based code running and I feel like this should be simple, but I can not figure out or find an example that does not use @deprecated functions.  My suspicion is that this is trivial and I'm going to feel dumb when someone shows me, but I would really appreciate some help.

A little background on what I have tried:
I somehow doubt it matters, but after learning how to write the interface files by hand (and getting them to work), I switched over to JNAerator.  JNAerator translates

```
MyStruct* mine
```

to

```
MyStruct mine
```

in Java.  This confuses me a bit because in Java this could only be used to point to a single object.  At one point I looked at using

```
MyStruct** mine
```

which translates to

```
PointerByReference mine
```

But this seems like overkill because I don't need to modify the structs, or ever access them again for that matter.  I have tried everything I can think of from this point on but I have never managed to successfully send more than the first struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After re-reading your question (pass structures from Java to C++), here's what you can do:

```
// Assuming a native signature like this:
// call_native_function(MyStruct** struct_list, int count)

MyStruct.ByReference[] list = new MyStruct.ByReference[SIZE];
for (int i=0;i < list.length;i++) {
    list[i] = new MyStruct.ByReference();
    // Initialize the struct as needed
}
// Call whatever native method...
nativeLibrary.call_native_function(list, list.length);
```

See also the [JNA FAQ](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.md#when-should-i-use-structurebyreference-structurebyvalue-structure).

Comment: Yeah, this is what I did.  I did that thing where I solved it shortly after I asked the question.  Sometimes I think SO is magic and asking the question shows me the answer.